# Java won't install on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have begun working of building a custom Android HAL. In order to do this I am setting up a new Linux install and had an error when trying to run make.

```
make could not find jdk tools.jar
```

After digging around forums and attempting to solve this problem I tried to uninstall Java and reinstall it. Now when I type this:

```
java -version
```

I get this error:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:....
```

This suggests it's uninstalled. However, when I go to install with

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

I get told this:

```
openjdk-11-jre-headless is already the newest version (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1).
```

So obviously somewhere it thinks it's still installed but I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: I would recommend to move this question to askubuntu.com

Comment: Might be an issue with PATH.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues here.

1. you don't have Java added to your system path and environment. $JAVA_HOME is likely not set and $JAVA_HOME/bin not added to the path.
2. Java 11 does not come with tools.jar as the entire Java packaging system was changed in Java 9 or 10. Install JDK 8 instead.
3. You're installing a JRE where you need a JDK.

Download the latest JDK 8 for your platform from http://java.oracle.com and follow the installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

## Android SDK setup

### -Method 1 :

### Update Ubuntu

You should always update your system first before you do anything else. Run the following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

And install the required package if you don’t have it already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

### Install Java

**using ubuntu terminal :**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

```

Add JAVA_HOME to path via ~/.bashrc

**using ubuntu terminal :**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Check what Java version you’re using:

```
java -version
```

The output should be something like:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.4+11) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 8.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

### -Method 2 :

### Install Java using the Oracle JDK:

**Step 1: Update Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

**And install the required package if you don’t have it already installed:**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

**Step 2: Add the Java repository**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

**And then update your package list again:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 3: Install Java**

Currently, Java 9 is considered stable, though you’ll find many other outdated tutorials saying 9 is still a “developer/beta/preview” release, it’s actually stable. So you should install Java 9. Java 10 should be released soon (March 2018).

So to install the JDK 9th (stable) version, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

If, for any reason, you need the 8th version, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And that’s it. You can now configure your Java

### Configure your Java

**Set the JAVA_HOME variable**

You’ll most likely need to set the JAVA_HOME variable so other applications can find the location of your Java installation. To find the Java installation path, run the previous command again:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

And copy the installation path – second column – under “Path”.

Next, open the file “/etc/environment” with a text editor

```
nano /etc/environment
```

And add the following line at the end of the file:

```
JAVA_HOME="/your/java/installation-path"
```

Of course, make sure you update the path with the one you previously copied, example:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"
```

Save the file and then reload it:

```
source /etc/environment
```

To test if everything’s done right, you can check your JAVA_HOME variable using:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

And the output should be your Java installation path.

### Install Android Studio

Download ZIP archive for Linux from: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html
1. move the .zip to /opt
2. extract it
3. chown the folder to your name
4. chmod 777 studio.sh and run it for the installer

Now the android sdk is installed to ~/Android/Sdk
It's preferred to add ~/Android/Sdk folders to your path:

**using ubuntu terminal :**

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

```

Run `android`, install the images (atom, etc) and then navigate to Tools -> Manage AVDs and create a new image
Make sure to install the android-23 version and confirm it exists in ~/Android/Sdk/platforms/

FYI: Worked like a charm. Bt I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

hope this helps!
by QAL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you loads for your replies. I managed to install Java in the end by simply using --reinstall.

However, my original problem remains. I am trying to build LK bootloader images for the Dragonboard 410c from 96boards. When I go to run make I get the error

```
Your version is: openjdk version "1.8.0_171" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode).
```

The required version is: "1.7.x"

I know in older versions of Ubuntu openjdk wasn't supported but it is now and I can successful build the AOSP for Dragonboard 410c available from the 96boards website.

So why would I get the error for one when the other builds?

Many many thanks!!